# Two elements of javascript are clashing in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

There are two elements on [this page](http://changinggears.org.uk/) that have Javascript attached. The donate box on the left, and the image slider in the centre. The image slider just rolls round on a time delay while the donate box changes its left-position on hover, then returns when hover is released. This works OK in FF and Chrome.

In IE there seems to be some sort of clash between the two elements. As soon as I run the hover command the slider stops working. The hover also only works once, and needs a page refresh before it'll run again.

Is there any way to fix this?

---

This is the code for the image slider:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

//Set Default State of each portfolio piece
$(".paging").show();
$(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

//Get size of images, how many there are, then determin the size of the image reel.
var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

//Adjust the image reel to its new size
$(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});


//Paging + Slider Function
rotate = function(){    

    var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
    var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

    $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
    $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

    //Slider Animation
    $(".image_reel").animate({ 
        left: -image_reelPosition}, {
            duration: 2000,
            easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
        })      
}



//Rotation + Timing Event
rotateSwitch = function(){      
    play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds

        $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
        if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
            $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
        }

        rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
    }, 6000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)
};

rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

//On Hover

$(".image_reel a").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
}, function() {
    rotateSwitch(); //Resume rotation
}); 

//On Click
$(".paging a").click(function() {   
    $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
    //Reset Timer
    clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
    rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
    rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
    return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
}); 

});
</script>
```

and this is for the donate box:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#donatebox').hover(function() {
    $('#donatebox').animate({
      'left': parseInt($(this).css('left'),10) == 295 ?
        $(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000,'easeOutQuad') :
        295
    });
  });
});
```

---

It's beyond me so I've worked round it another way that doesn't need parsing (which I really don't understand...)

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#donatebox').mouseenter(

function() {
$('#donatebox').animate({"marginLeft": -5}, 1000, "easeOutBounce");
});
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#donatebox").mouseleave (

function() {
$(this).animate({"marginLeft": -5}, 20).animate({"marginLeft": -305}, 700,     "easeOutQuad"); 

});
});
```

Comment: Have you debugged the script with the IE Developer Tools console? I see Javascript errors that occur just after the Donate box folds back in. That's why nothing works afterwards. I think assuming a "clash" is leaping to conclusions here.

Comment: @Shadow: ...on the website, plain to see.

Comment: @Tom I prefer to see relevant code only, much faster than wade through the whole code and guess what might be wrong.

Comment: There's a few validation errors (duplicate IDs) at W3C if that helps: http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=http%3A%2F%2Fchanginggears.org.uk%2F

Comment: @Shadow: Testcases are great! But you implied that the code had not been provided at all, which is not true.

Comment: @shadow relevant sections edited in now

Answer (score 1):

Something's causing a Javascript error in your jQuery "easing" plugin, when the `div` has eased back into its slot. This is why no scripts are running after you use the Donate box once.

If you use Developer Tools in IE, you'll find that the error is caught. Then (although the animation is decoupled so you can't just go up the callstack) it is deducible that the issue is in the animation that you instigate from your custom.js:

```
$('#donatebox').animate({
  'left': parseInt($(this).css('left'),10) == 295 ?
    $(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000,'easeOutQuad') :
    295
});
```

^ Doesn't look right to me.

You also have duplicate HTML node IDs `overimage`. IDs are *unique*; perhaps you meant to use classes?

Comment: class/id fixed now. it wasn't floating the image over the text as an class but it seems to be working now.

Comment: fx.elem.style[ fx.prop ] = (fx.prop === "width" || fx.prop === "height" ? Math.max(0, fx.now) : fx.now) + fx.unit;

Comment: that's the error read in developer tools, from the jquery library. what does it mean?

Comment: @upandatom: Notice how, when the donate box is open, you're asking it to animate leftwards to a value of `$(this).animate({'left': '0px'}, 1000,'easeOutQuad')` .. which evaluates to a jQuery object, not a numeric value. You're passing an _Invalid Argument_ to jQuery.

Comment: @upandatom: You need to examine that line of code, and explain to yourself what the purpose is of that embedded conditional. What is the code _really_ doing? What did you intend for it to do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it help you.

[Ticket on jQuery Bug Tracker](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/10050)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by `Invalid Argument` exception on Line: 8538 of jquery-latest.js

Comment: Aye, I saw that, but that's the global JQuery library. Why would that produce an error, and surely there's nothing I can do to fix that?

Comment: Because of the way Javascript works, you can indeed have caused the error... it's just that it's not until the function call is deep within jQuery's internals that it's caught. Usually you can examine the call stack to get a better idea of how you triggered it (usually by passing something wrong in a parameter to a jQuery function).